# How to apply a queue mechanism in postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a table named "`infrastructure`" in my postgresql databse. So when a record inserted or updated to this table, 4 different trigger is working. But each trigger takes 1-2 seconds. This is a performance issue for me. So can I send the resords in a queue in postgresql? Then consumers can do trigger operations. Is this possible? Does listen/notify works for this purpose?

Comment: Is it necessary they be processed in a particular order?  Is there a natural way of knowing, by looking at the row (or its children) , if the trigger work has already been done?  What happens if someone (other than a queue worker) wants to see a row that has not yet been fully pocessed?

Answer (score 0):

Usually queues are better left outside of the DB using dedicated solutions - but if you insist on keeping it in the database then you can try the [mBus extension](https://code.google.com/archive/p/mbus/).
I have not used it so can not comment on it.